# Failing to install Python smilite using PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, conda

I want to install the Python package smilite (https://github.com/rasbt/smilite) within my current PyCharm Python project. I do the usual Python Packages -> PyPI repository -> look up "smilite" -> Install (latest version).

I'm getting a failed installation:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - smilite

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/numba/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/numba/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

The website says to use `pip install`, but clearly, PyCharm is using Conda. I don't want to wreck my PyCharm environment; my software is running, but I need this installed. How do I ask PyCharm to pip install rather than conda install for this **one** package into my current environment?

I am using Windows 11, and the Python interpreter (3.9) inside PyCharm looks to be managed by Conda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in the PyCharm Terminal.
Activate your Conda environment (if it is not already) by running the appropriate command (replace the name with your conda env name):

```
conda activate your_name_of_conda_environment
```

Once your Conda environment is activated, you can use pip to install the package:

```
pip install smilite
```

This will use pip to install the "smilite" package **just into your Conda environment**.

Using pip in this way **won't** affect your PyCharm environment, as you're installing the package only within the activated Conda environment.

Comment: Thanks dominikfey, that's extremely helpful. So far, so good. It's installed and my current environment inside PyCharm can see it. Hence, you answered my questions :-) Now, I need to make it work!

Comment: If you have any further problems, feel free to contact me

Comment: what do you mean by `Using pip in this way won't affect your PyCharm environment`? In the scope of this question, the pycharm project uses the conda env, so it does effect the environment used by pycharm

Comment: @FlyingTeller You're correct, and I apologize for any confusion. When I mentioned that using pip in this way won't affect your PyCharm environment, I meant that it won't negatively impact the stability or functionality of the PyCharm project since one's still installing the package within the Conda environment that PyCharm manages. The statement was not intended to imply that it wouldn't affect the environment used by PyCharm at all.

Answer (score 1):

find the pip.exe executor, and use the command in terminal

assume the path is

"F:\kksoftware\miniconda3\Scripts"

```
F:\kksoftware\miniconda3\Scripts\pip.exe install smilite
```

then pip will install the package to your python envirnment directory.